# Clang linker "Library not found for -lCocoa"

Tags: macos, clang, linker-errors, premake

Building on [TheChernos Game Engine series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dC-V-N3m0Go4deliWHPFwT), I've tried to write the system for MacOSX instead of Windows.

After making GLFW, glad and ImGui compile, the -lCocoa library is not found with command
`ld: library not found for -lCocoa`. Since I'm using IOKit, CoreVideo and OpenGL the same way I presume the same errors will show when I cross this bridge.

In his series he uses premake5, and this is the premake5 for the workspace, covering the static library and a usage example app of the Engine.

```
workspace "Neurex"
    architecture "x64"

    configurations {"Debug", "Release", "Dist"}

startproject "NXSandbox"
outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

includeDir = {}
includeDir["GLFW"] = "Neurex/vendor/GLFW/include"
includeDir["glad"] = "Neurex/vendor/glad/include"
includeDir["spdlog"] = "Neurex/vendor/spdlog/include"
includeDir["imgui"] = "Neurex/vendor/imgui"
includeDir["glm"] = "Neurex/vendor/glm"

group "Dependencies"
    include "Neurex/vendor/GLFW"
    include "Neurex/vendor/glad"
    include "Neurex/vendor/imgui"
group ""


project "Neurex"
    location "Neurex"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "on"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    pchheader "nxpch.h"
    pchsource "Neurex/src/nxpch.cpp"

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/glm/glm/**.hpp",
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/glm/glm/**.inl"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src",
        "%{includeDir.spdlog}",
        "%{includeDir.GLFW}",
        "%{includeDir.glad}",
        "%{includeDir.imgui}",
        "%{includeDir.glm}"
    }


    filter "system:windows"
        systemversion "latest"

        links
        {
            "GLFW",
            "glad",
            "imgui",
            "opengl32.lib",
        }

        defines 
        {
            "NX_PT_WIN",
            "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE",
            "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
        }

    filter "system:macosx"
        links {
            "GLFW",
            "glad",
            "imgui",
            "Cocoa",
            "CoreVideo",
            "OpenGL",
            "IOKit"
        }

        defines {
            "NX_PT_OSX",
            "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE",
            "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"   
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "NX_DEBUG"
        symbols "on"
        runtime "Debug"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "NX_RELEASE"
        optimize "on"
        runtime "Release"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "NX_DIST"
        optimize "on"
        runtime "Release"



project "NXSandbox"
    location "NXSandbox"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "on"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs {
        "Neurex/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "Neurex/src",
        "Neurex/vendor",
        "%{includeDir.glm}",
    }

    links {
        "Neurex"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines { "NX_PT_WIN" }

    filter "system:macosx"
        links {
            "Cocoa",
            "IOKit",
            "OpenGL",
            "CoreVideo"
        }

        defines {
            "NX_PT_OSX",
            "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE",
            "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "NX_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"
        runtime "Debug"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "NX_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"
        runtime "Release"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "NX_DIST"
        optimize "On"
        runtime "Release"
```

The static library compiles, the Sandbox provides the linking problem.

I'm using Apple Clang v13.0.0, GNU Make 3.81, premake5.0.0 alpha 16.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved by adding ".framework" to the declarations of the frameworks:

```
Cocoa -> Cocoa.framework
```